# URL of Blobs in Azure with directory structure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

**Assembly in use**: Assembly Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.1.0

**What I want to do**:
In my Azure storage, I have images stored as a blob, in the following fashion

[image]

I want to get the URLs of all the image blobs along with their last modified timestamp.

Please note that `Image1` and `Image4` might have the same name.

**What I have tried**:

1. I tried `ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(BlobContinuationToken currentToken)` from the root of the container and by using `GetDirectoryReference(string relativeAddress)` but couldn't get the desired result.
2. Though a bit off track, I am able to get the blob details by `GetBlockBlobReference(string blobName);`

What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, remember that blob storage does not actually have folders, they are virtual. So you really have blobs with names e.g. "Folder1/Image1.png". ListBlobsSegemented should give you all the blobs, can you show the code you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ListBlobsSegmentedAsync` method has 2 overloads that contain the `useFlatBlobListing` argument. These overloads accept 7 or 8 arguments, and I count 6 in your code.

Use the following code to list all blob in container.

```
public static async Task test()
{
    StorageCredentials storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials("xxx", "xxxxx");
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentials, true);
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("container");
    BlobContinuationToken blobContinuationToken = null;
    var resultSegment = await container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(
         prefix: null,
         useFlatBlobListing: true,
         blobListingDetails: BlobListingDetails.None,
         maxResults: null,
         currentToken: blobContinuationToken,
         options: null,
         operationContext: null
     );

     // Get the value of the continuation token returned by the listing call.
     blobContinuationToken = resultSegment.ContinuationToken;
     foreach (IListBlobItem item in resultSegment.Results)
     {
          Console.WriteLine(item.Uri);
     }
}
```

The result is as below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, by mistake I was using 'ListBlobsSegmentedAsync' of 'CloudBlobClient'.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this override of [`ListBlobsSegmentedAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.listblobssegmentedasync?view=azure-dotnet-legacy#Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlobContainer_ListBlobsSegmentedAsync_System_String_System_Boolean_Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Blob_BlobListingDetails_System_Nullable_System_Int32__Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Blob_BlobContinuationToken_Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Blob_BlobRequestOptions_Microsoft_Azure_Storage_OperationContext_) with the following parameters:

```
prefix: ""

useFlatBlobListing: true

blobListingDetails: BlobListingDetails.All

maxResults: 5000

currentToken: null or the continuation token returned
```

This will return you a list of all blobs (including inside virtual folders)